# Error in Openquery Stored Procedure

Tags: sql

To keep this as simple as possible I have just copied the line of code causing an error. I'm trying to run a openquery in a stored procedure and keep getting the following error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '*'.
```

I'm pretty sure it is to do with where I have quotations but I really need a second pair of eyes as I have tried all sorts of combinations:

```
SET @SQL_ResultID = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([23-SQL3000], ''SELECT ResultID FROM [Portfolio].[dbo].[Program] P INNER JOIN [Portfolio].[dbo].[Results] A ON P.ProgramID = A.ProgramID WHERE ProgramName = ''''' + @P + ''''' AND ResultsName = ''''' + @A + ''''''')';
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you paste the final value of the @SQL_ResultID after its set.

Comment: For this SP the value of @SQL_ResultID = 47

Comment: I meant the sql query, after all the substitutions were done for your parameters @p and @A

Comment: Sorry - `SET @SQL_ResultID = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([23-SQL3000], ''SELECT ResultID FROM [Portfolio].[dbo].[Program] P INNER JOIN [Portfolio].[dbo].[Results] A ON P.ProgramID = A.ProgramID WHERE ProgramName = ''''Europe'''' AND ResultsName = ''''UK Q1 - Losses'''''')';`

Comment: Your quotes seems rights to me. Could you try running this see if it works. `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([23-SQL3000], ''SELECT top 10 ResultID FROM [Portfolio].[dbo].[Program] P'')'`

Comment: Do you have a valid LinkedServer by the name `23-SQL3000` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70768/discussion-between-carlos80-and-soultrain).